# Unterminated String Constant: Can't fix

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm facing an issue with my project that when it gets built it throws the error

```
"SyntaxError: Unterminated string constant (363:41) while parsing file: /raid/jenkins/edublocks/ui/build/blocks/index.js"
```

Line 363 is

```
toolBoxXml += fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'src', 'blocks', 'pi', 'gpiozero', 'toolbox.xml'));
```

Which imports files in this folder: https://github.com/AllAboutCode/EduBlocks/tree/master/ui/src/blocks/pi/gpiozero

However I can't see any issues in any of those files. Any help or a second pair of eyes would really help!

Comment: Could you provide more context in the file - perhaps a few lines above and below it?

Comment: Related: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Unterminated_string_literal

Comment: I can't see anything wrong. Maybe you can post the full generated index.js somewhere, like gist.github.com?

Comment: This is the index.js file https://gist.github.com/JoshuaLowe1002/a437699477131338960e544bf3ca816c

@AugustLilleaas

Comment: Also @chazsolo https://gist.github.com/JoshuaLowe1002/a437699477131338960e544bf3ca816c

Comment: Not sure where the problem is but, in general, I would recommend to eliminate all the repetition you have in the https://gist.github.com/JoshuaLowe1002/a437699477131338960e544bf3ca816c file, as a switch with over 100 cases is definitely going to be a problem sooner or later (in this case, it already might be).

With the repetition gone, chances are the very difficult-to-spot syntax error will also go away.